# Злых людей наказывают - добрых воспевают. БСП или ОЧП?

Tags: пунктуация

Злых людей наказывают - добрых воспевают.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение или однородные члены предложения, между которыми пропущен противительный союз?

Answer (score 2):

Это бессоюзно-сложное предложение с противительными отношениями между его частями.

Однородные члены — это члены предложения, которые обычно отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и связаны с одним и тем же словом в предложении. В вашем же примере нет такой связи.

Ср.: **БСП.** Служить бы рад — прислуживаться тошно. Чин следовал ему — он службу вдруг оставил (Гр.); Шить сядет — не умеет взять иголку; её бранят — она себе молчит (П.); Прошла неделя, месяц — он к себе домой не возвращался (П.); Я хвать за пояс — пистолета нет (Л.); Я стал звать хозяина — молчат; стучу — молчат (Л.).

**Однородные члены предложения.**

*Теперь море сияло уже не сплошь, а лишь в нескольких местах.* (Обстоятельства "сплошь и в нескольких местах относятся к сказуемому "сияло ".)

Comment: Обстоятельства "сплошь" и "в нескольких местах" относятся не к подлежащему, а к сказуемому СИЯЛО.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Однако завершите правку: надо ещё убрать слово "подлежащему" и заменить его на "сказуемому".

Answer (score 2):

**Злых людей наказывают — добрых воспевают.**

Я думаю, что это БСП. С одной стороны, сказуемые имеют одинаковую грамматическую форму, мыслится один производитель действия, но степень спаянности у них минимальна: у каждого сказуемого собственный распространитель (общего распространителя нет), отношения между ними противительные.

У Розенталя в теме БСП рассмотрены такие предложения (со значением противопоставления):

Не сумку у Мишки украли — последнюю надежду похитили (Нев.); Косили версту — выкосили грош (М. Г.);